# Javascript document.images.length returning 0

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to get all of the images with classname of tile into an array called tiles. I've tried a few things but it keeps giving me 0 length arrays/nodelists.

What am I doing wrong?

```
for(var i =0; i<document.images.length; i++){
    var thumb = document.images[i]
    if(thumb.className == "tile" && thumb.parentNode.tagName == "A")
        tiles.push(thumb);
}
```

I have also tried

```
var allInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

for(var i =0; i<allInputs.length; i++){
    if(allInputs[i].className == "tile" tiles.push(allInputs[i]);
}
```

EDIT: Per request, here is all of the HTML code.

```
<body>
<form id="ct" action="">
  <div id="head">
     <img src="kgtitle.jpg" alt="Kiddergarden" />
  </div>
  <div id="menu">
     <img src="kgmenu.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div id="title">
     <img src="ctitle.jpg" alt="Matching Game" />
  </div>

  <div id="board">
     <a href="#"><img src="tile.jpg" class="tile" alt="" /></a>
     <a href="#"><img src="tile.jpg" class="tile" alt="" /></a>
     <a href="#"><img src="tile.jpg" class="tile" alt="" /></a>
     <a href="#"><img src="tile.jpg" class="tile" alt="" /></a>
     <br />
     <a href="#"><img src="tile.jpg" class="tile" alt="" /></a>
     <a href="#"><img src="tile.jpg" class="tile" alt="" /></a>
     <a href="#"><img src="tile.jpg" class="tile" alt="" /></a>
     <a href="#"><img src="tile.jpg" class="tile" alt="" /></a>
     <br />
     <a href="#"><img src="tile.jpg" class="tile" alt="" /></a>
     <a href="#"><img src="tile.jpg" class="tile" alt="" /></a>
     <a href="#"><img src="tile.jpg" class="tile" alt="" /></a>
     <a href="#"><img src="tile.jpg" class="tile" alt="" /></a>
     <br />
     <a href="#"><img src="tile.jpg" class="tile" alt="" /></a>
     <a href="#"><img src="tile.jpg" class="tile" alt="" /></a>
     <a href="#"><img src="tile.jpg" class="tile" alt="" /></a>
     <a href="#"><img src="tile.jpg" class="tile" alt="" /></a>
  </div>


  <div id="main">

     <p>Play the Concentration game! Click the tiles on the left and
        match pairs of identical images.
        <br /><br />
        Click the <b>Reload Tiles</b>
        button below to randomize the position of the tiles and play
        again.
        <br /><br />
        Click the <b>Show Tiles</b> button to view the
        solution.
     </p>

  </div>

  <div id="controls">
     <p>
        <input type="button" value="Reload Tiles" id="reload" />
        <input type="button" value="Show Tiles" id="showAll" />
     </p>
  </div>

  <address>
     Kiddergarden &#183;
     A safe site on the Web for kids and families
  </address>
```

This is the entirety of my javascript code

```
function addEvent(object, evName, fnName, cap) {
if (object.attachEvent)
    object.attachEvent("on" + evName, fnName);
else if (object.addEventListener)
    object.addEventListener(evName, fnName, cap);
}

function randomSort(arr) {

arr.sort(function () {
    return 0.5 - Math.random();
});

}

function setOpacity(object, value) {


// Apply the opacity value for IE and non-IE browsers
object.style.filter = "alpha(opacity = " + value + ")";
object.style.opacity = value/100;

}
var flipCount = 0;
var firstFlip;
var secondFlip;

addEvent(window, "load", setupTiles(),false);

function setupTiles() {
var tiles = new Array();

alert(document.getElementsByTagName('img').length);
for(var i =0; i<document.getElementsByTagName("img").length; i++){
    var thumb = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    thumb = thumb[i];
    if(thumb.className == "tile" && thumb.parentNode.tagName == "A")
        tiles.push(thumb);
}


var tileImages = new Array(tiles.length);

for(var j = 0; i < tileImages.length/2; j++){
    tileImages[j] = new Image("tileimage"+j+".jpg");
}

for(var k = tileImages.length/2; i<tileImages.length;k++){
    tileImages[k] = new Image("tileimage"+(i-tileImages.length)+".jpg");
}

randomSort(tileImages);

for(var l =0; i<tiles.length;l++){
    tiles[l].image = tileImages[l];
    tiles[l].onclick = flipTile;
}

/*document.getElementById("showAll").onclick = function () {
 for(var i =0; i<tiles.length;i++){
 tiles[i].src = tiles[i].image.src;
 }
 }

 document.getElementById("reload").onclick = function () {
 location.reload();
 }*/

}

function flipTable(){
if(flipCount == 0){
    this.src = this.image.src;
    firstFlip = this;
    flipCount++;
}
else if(flipCount == 1){
    this.src = this.image.src;
    secondFlip = this;
    flipCount++;
    checkTiles();
}

return false;
}

function checkTiles() {
if(firstFlip.image.src != secondFlip.image.src){
    flipBack();
}
else{
    flipCount=0;
    firstFlip.opacity = 0.70;
    firstFlip.style.filter = "alpha(opacity= 70)";
    firstFlip.onclick = function () {
        return false;
    }
    secondFlip.opacity = 0.70;
    secondFlip.style.filter = "alpha(opacity= 70)";
    secondFlip.onclick = function () {
        return false;
    }

}
}

function flipBack() {
firstFlip.src = "tile.jpg";
secondFlip.src = "tile.jpg";
flipCount = 0;
}
```

Comment: is `tile` the only class?

Comment: Yes, the only class in the html is `tile`

Comment: You need to show us your html code.

Comment: @KWhite No he is asking, images are having only class `tile` or something like `class="tile class2 class3"` ?

Comment: @Tresdin I have added the HTML code to the post.

Comment: is your `addEvent` working properly? when you pass the function name with parenthesis this function will be called immediately.. change `addEvent(window, "load", setupTiles(),false);` to `addEvent(window, "load", setupTiles,false);`

Comment: Your code works fine. https://jsfiddle.net/d5b4L660/

Comment: @DanielAlmeida that is exactly it. Now i get 19 objects. Now to fix the rest of the code to get it to flip tiles and such. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

your script is fine, I just tested it. it probably returns 0 because you add the script to the top of you file, just make sure you add in the end:

```
<html>
   <body>
     <div id="board">
        <a href="#"><img src="tile.jpg" class="tile" alt="" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="tile.jpg" class="tile" alt="" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="tile.jpg" class="tile" alt="" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="tile.jpg" class="tile" alt="" /></a>
     </div>
   </body>
   <script>
      var tiles = [];
      for(var i =0; i<document.images.length; i++){
         var thumb = document.images[i]
         if(thumb.className == "tile" && thumb.parentNode.tagName == "A")
            tiles.push(thumb);
      }
      alert(tiles.length)
   </script>
</html>
```

At least is the only cause I could find to return 0. Please let me know if it solved your issue.

If you ar importing the script from a different file, just add the import on the end, like this:

```
<html>
   <body>
     <div id="board">
        <a href="#"><img src="tile.jpg" class="tile" alt="" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="tile.jpg" class="tile" alt="" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="tile.jpg" class="tile" alt="" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="tile.jpg" class="tile" alt="" /></a>
     </div>
   </body>
   <script src="myscript.js"></script>
</html>
```

a third option is to add your code in a function on document ready listener:

```
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
      var tiles = [];
      for(var i =0; i<document.images.length; i++){
         var thumb = document.images[i]
         if(thumb.className == "tile" && thumb.parentNode.tagName == "A")
            tiles.push(thumb);
      }
      alert(tiles.length)
  });
```